# The _data of an EAV model

Tags: product, catalog, eav

I understand that the _data of a simple model (e.g., `cataloginventory/stock_item`) is an array of field value pairs, which corresponding to the fields of database tables. I was curious to know the content of _data for EAV models, so I checked the _data of `catalog/product` using the debug() function.

The finding is that it contains the field values pairs of `catalog_product_entity`, and also some attribute of this entity. They are make sense to me. The point I can't understand is that is also contain a pair:

```
...    
[stock_item (Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Item)] => Array
            (
                [item_id] => 1
                [product_id] => 1
                [stock_id]
                ......
            )
...
```

, which is an instance of `cataloginventory/stock_item`. This is neither an attribute of catalog/product entity, nor a field in `catalog_product_entity`, why it is included?

Is there a convention of _data for EAV models?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In theory `_data` can contain anything.
You can add your custom values in there by using `setData($key, $value)`.
Usually it contains like you said, the values for the columns in the table, or for attributes in case it's an EAV entity, but for some particular cases it can contain other values.
This happens for the products for example.
Here is why.
In the module `Mage_CatalogInventory` there is an observer for the event `catalog_product_load_after`. This event is called each time you call `$product->load()`.
The method executed is `Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Observer::addInventoryData`.
This one calls `$productStockItem->assignProduct($product);`.
If we dig deeper we end up in `Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Item::assignProduct` that calls at one point `$product->setStockItem($this);`. This is eqivalent to `$product->setData('stock_item', $this)`.
So you end up having the instance of `Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Item` in `_data['stock_item']`.